# Google coral object detection retraining, missing the ckpt file

Tags: google-coral

from https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/#configure-your-training-pipeline

we should specify the path to a ckpt file (the checkpoints/weights of the SSD v1 model):

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "/tensorflow/models/research/learn_pet/ckpt/model.ckpt"
```

But nowhere before, in the tutorial, it is indicated how to obtain this ckpt file.

The only "indication" is that we can download some files of the model from https://coral.ai/models/object-detection/ , but the only files that there is are model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 , model.ckpt.index and model.ckpt.meta

Help ?